# WPF SignalR Server

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm really stuck and need some help.
I have a .NET Core 3.1 WPF application, which decodes basketball scoreboard data and now I need to send this data over to .html file. The .html file is opened once through CasparCG server as a template and needs to somehow have it's data update real-time.

I currently thinking that the best way to do this is to have a SignalR server in the WPF app and a html template running a SignalR client. One of the requirements is that I have to be able to start and stop the SignalR server with a button click.

The problem is, I have absolutely no idea where to start as it seems that there's very little information regarding hosting a SignalR server on WPF app.

Comment: Hello, you should first implement examples like this (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181555/SignalChat-WPF-SignalR-Chat-Application) so you could start to develop your app.

Comment: And you have this microsoft documentation to start with :)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could host ASP.NET Core (including SignalR) in your WPF application.

Reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` NuGet package as a framework reference in your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Create an `IHost` using the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` API and start it and stop it as required when your buttons are clicked:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private IHost _host;

        private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _host?.Dispose();
            _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder
                    .UseUrls("http://localhost:5100")
                    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSignalR())
                    .Configure(app =>
                    {
                        app.UseRouting();
                        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapHub<StreamHub>("/streamHub"));
                    }))
               .Build();

            await _host.StartAsync();
        }


        private async void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_host != null)
            {
                await _host.StopAsync();
                _host.Dispose();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            _host?.Dispose();
            base.OnClosing(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Though I'm still trying to figure out how to send a message from the server to client..

Comment: @Vilius: You may for example use an `IHubContext`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1. Or the `Clients` property of a hub: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

Comment: I've read the docs, but I feel like a dumbass. In the MainWindow class if I wanted to get the HubContext, how would I got about it?

private IHubContext<ScoreboardTime> _hubContext = ... ?

Comment: @Vilius - Did you figure our how to implement this? I would appreciate if you could share your main code or methods related to this.